# Comparing two logit models

Tags: regression, logit

Folks,

Would appreciate any advice on the following topic.

My question I would like to answer is the following.

What are the determinants of being a First Time Buyer of a House?

Based on a survey I have a dataset which contains a binary indicator if an individual identified themselves as a First Time buyer or not. The idea is to fit a logistic regression model where my dependent variable would be the binary indicator and I would have a number of controls such as; Age, Income, House Price, Region where house is located, nationality of owner.

However, I have a suspicion that the FTB indicator in the survey may underestimate the proportion of first time buyers i.e. individuals who should be a FTB are not denoting themselves as one.

Therefore, I have developed my own method to independently identify whether someone may be a first time buyer. This involves examining administrative records based on property purchases.

I would like to fit a logit model for this too and compare results. Note that the cohorts are exactly the same.

Is it possible to compare and contrast the results of these two models and identify whether one is a better predictor or not?

Basically I need some way to validate my own methodology.

Any ideas are welcomed.

Comment: The dependent variable has different values in each case?

Comment: The Dependent variable is binary in both cases. For example we sample of 100 people. Are dependent variable based of the survey response has a split of 40/60. The split based on the new methodology is 20/80. We know for the 100 individuals where the values match and where they do not.

Comment: Then I don’t see how it makes sense to assess whether a model for one is more predictive than a model for the other.  The issue as I understand it is which variable is more accurate.  How well you can predict what might be the wrong value in the first place is beside the point.

Answer (score 1):

Is your personal method more reliable than the self-reported information (SRI)? If so, then forget about the self-reported information. If your method does not make use of the SRI then you could specify the SRI as a model predictor (as a control variable). First thing I would do is to cross-tabulate the 2 variables - Eventually you could specify another logistic model of the matching proba. Or you could also use a multinomial logistic regression with 3 modalities: (1) FTB (The 2 methods are in agreement); (2) Not FTB (The 2 methods are in agreement); (3) Uncertain (The 2 methods disagree).

Answer (score 0):

You could compare log likelihoods for sake of model fitting, but that's not predictive validity, which is what you are wanting. You say they are the same cohort. Can you make exact matches? Maybe follow up on those people where the models disagree, via interview or questionaire, and use that new data to re-train your model.

Answer (score -2):

Just a quick idea: first you can do the Likelihood Ratio Test for each of the 2 models, just to check if a certain model (logit) fits the dataset well enough

If resulting p-value is under a certain threshold (e.g. 0.05) you can drop the related model (as it does not fit the dataset well enough) : so you succeed to reject the null hypothesis (that model fits the dataset)

If in both cases you fail to reject the null hypothesis (so both the models fit the dataset well enough) you can check whether one fits better than the other, comparing the p-values and keeping the higher one

Another idea could be to use a metric focused on representing unexplained variance: even if in case of logit, contrary to linear regression, you do not have R^2 there are pseudo R^2 developed for this purpose (let me check and come back to you later with an edit)

Comment: LR test should only be used to compare nested models (eg Y = X1 + X2 vs Y = X1).

Comment: @Umka 1) can you provide source for your claim? 2) Does my answer deserve a -1 considering it also includes another point which you have not criticized?

Comment: Don't have a particular reference in mind. Any stat textbook would explain how/when LR test can be used. Wiki page too. LR test is based on the difference in loglik between the "large" (unconstrained) and "small" (constrained) models. This difference is known as "deviance" and this quantity has to be positive. When you use LR test to compare models with different DVs, there is no guarantee that the "large" (or reference) model will perform better than its competitor, such that you could end up with a negative deviance.  If the 2 models have the same number of model parameters, then 0 DF test

Comment: Re the down vote, I did not intended to be mean - I simply believed your answer was misleading but will see if I can remove it later on

Comment: Being a bit more specific: I haven't heard of doing an LR test on one model. Your first sentence seems to read as: do an LR test on each model, to check if each model fits well enough. We definitely use LR tests to compare a pair of nested models - the null hypothesis is that the more restrictive model, i.e. the one with fewer parameters, and the less restrictive one fit the data equally well. Was that what you meant?

Comment: OK I understand I explained that part in a bad way: what I wanted to say is to run each LR against a model with fewer predictors so to check if logit is actually an improvement 
I'd like to edit the answer to better specify this and so, hopefully, I'll have the malus points removed

Comment: LR test do require models to be nested as mentioned.  They are most commonly used to test a reduced model vs a full model to reduce complexity. A link from minitab, which i have never used, but is considered a reliable source.  https://support.minitab.com/en-us/minitab/18/help-and-how-to/quality-and-process-improvement/capability-analysis/supporting-topics/distributions-and-transformations-for-nonnormal-data/what-is-the-likelihood-ratio-test/